# Use CSS only to position dynamic DIV off-screen then slide down with animation

Tags: css, html

We have a DIV that is centered vertically in its parent and shows different text at different times, meaning its height is not fixed.

Is it possible to use CSS only to position this DIV just off the screen, at the top, then slide it down with animation?

We tried various combinations of `translateY` and `webkit-transform`, but these fail because `translateY` is based on the element's height, not the parent's, when using percentages. Using pixels doesn't work since the DIV's height varies.

A JavaScript solution is obviously possible, but is there a way to do this with CSS only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pastebin.com/pVmXyfxi

Not 100% sure if this is what you mean, but you can move the div off the screen with top:-1000px and then change the top: value on hover (or click or whatnot).  The animation part is defined in the div css settings and it runs when one of the settings is changed.